# matplotlib is now giving an 'Unknown property' AttributeError since update to Python 3:

Tags: linux, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using astroplan to set up some astronomical observations. Previously, when I ran my code using Python 2.7, it plotted the target on the sky properly.  Now, I have moved to Python 3.7 and I get an AttributError on the same code.

I took my larger code and stripped out everything that did not seem to trigger the error.  Here below is code that will generate the complaint.

```
from astroplan import Observer, FixedTarget
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.time import Time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astroplan.plots import plot_sky
import numpy as np

time = Time('2015-06-16 12:00:00')
subaru = Observer.at_site('subaru')
vega = FixedTarget.from_name('Vega')
sunset_tonight = subaru.sun_set_time(time, which='nearest')
vega_rise = subaru.target_rise_time(time, vega) + 5*u.minute
start = np.max([sunset_tonight, vega_rise])


plot_sky(vega, subaru, start)  
plt.show()
```

Expected result was a simple plot of the target, in this case, the star Vega, on the sky as seen by the Subaru telescope in Hawaii.  The astroplan docs give a tutorial that shows how it was to look at the very end of this page:

https://astroplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/summer_triangle.html

Instead, I now get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_sky.py", line 16, in <module>
    plot_sky(vega, subaru, start)  
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/utils/decorators.py", line 842, in plot_sky
    func = make_function_with_signature(func, name=name, **wrapped_args)
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/units/decorators.py", line 222, in wrapper
    return_ = wrapped_function(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/local/data/fugussd/rkbarry/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroplan/plots/sky.py", line 216, in plot_sky
    ax.set_thetagrids(range(0, 360, 45), theta_labels, frac=1.2)
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/polar.py", line 1268, in set_thetagrids
    t.update(kwargs)
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 187, in update
    super().update(kwargs)
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 916, in update
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 916, in <listcomp>
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
  File "/usr1/local/anaconda_py3/ana37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 912, in _update_property
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
AttributeError: Unknown property frac
```

Comment: The astroplan code uses an argument `frac` which does not exist in matplotlib. You either need to remove it from the source code or check if there is a newer version available.

Comment: I’m not at my computer, so I cannot try this right now. However, I’d like to point out that it worked previously when I was running python 2.7. I think that is the only change.

Comment: The `frac` parameter has been deprecated in matplotlib 2.1, and has ultimately been removed in matplotlib 3.0.